# The machine that Syncer is in is broken and the directory of the `syncer.meta` file is lost when using TiDB

Tags: distributed-database, tidb

Syncer GTID synchronously updates `syncer.meta`. If the machine that Syncer is in goes down, the directory of `syncer.meta` is lost. And I did not find the record information of GTID in TiDB. How to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

When you synchronize data using Syncer GTID, the `syncer.meta` file is constantly updated during the synchronization process. The current version of Syncer does not contain the design for high availability. The `syncer.meta` configuration file of Syncer is directly stored on the hard disks, which is similar to other tools in the MySQL ecosystem, such as Mydumper.

Two solutions:

- Put the `syncer.meta` file in a relatively secure disk. For example, use disks with RAID 1.
- Restore the location information of history synchronization according to the monitoring data that Syncer reports to Prometheus regularly. But the location information might be inaccurate due to the delay when a large amount of data is synchronized.